# How does The Great Suspender work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Google Chrome 53, Linux, and I used chrome.tabs.discard inside an extension and I got an error that chrome.tabs.discard isn't a function. I looked in the source code of the The Great Suspender but I can't figure out how does it suspend the tabs. Any help would be more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Chromium developers are working on the [automatic built-in suspend feature](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/DK189tnM8l4/PokaAA84AQAJ).

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.tabs.discard` is not a valid api **yet, it still [in Dev channel](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-discard) (Thanks Xan)**.

Take a look at its source code, nothing special, it just replace current page with a local html page.

```
function suspendTab(suspendedUrl) {

    reportState('suspended');

    if (suspendedUrl.indexOf('suspended.html') > 0) {
        window.location.replace(suspendedUrl);
    } else {
        window.location.href = suspendedUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful: it's not a valid API _yet_. It's currently in Dev channel: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-discard